# ProcessBuilder fails to find file if run from OSX App bundle

Tags: java, macos, processbuilder

We are having a bizarre problem with ProcessBuilder with the OSX version of our app.  This started when we switched to the universalJavaApplicationStub.  Previously we used the AppBundlerTask.
Note: can't do a sample class, as you need to build a full mac app bundle to see this result:

Our code to start the process is:

```
log.debug("render: {}", Arrays.toString(myCommandLine.toArray()));
log.debug("render: dir={}", m_workingDir);
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(myCommandLine);
processBuilder.directory(new File(m_workingDir));
final Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

and the log output looked like this:

```
render: [/Applications/EFI/Metrix/bin/cli/rasters, --saveasimg, --pagebox=MEDIABOX, --smoothing=All]
render: dir=/Applications/EFI/Metrix/bin/cli/
```

This resulted in the rasters app throwing an error to the log, indicating that is was NOT running from it's installed directory.  (which is the directory in the 2nd log line.)

It seems like the working directory is NOT the one I specified in the processBuilder.directory() call.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: Sounds like you cannot rely on current working directory being set (which is quite common).  You can ask the JVM where your class was loaded from, and derive the installation directory from that.  Or perhaps you can just use `myCommandLine[0]`?

Comment: I modified our code to invoke a shell script that did a "pwd".
The working directory is correct.

Comment: Try printing out the value of  `new File(m_workingDir).getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 0):

Working with the app vendor, it turns out that I now need to do a "unset CFProcessPath" before running their app.